# How to automate the mobile emulation in chrome browser in browserstack?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, browserstack, mobileemulation

I'm trying to automate the mobile emulation in chrome browser. So I have done in **local chrome execution successfully**, not sure about the browserstack chrome mobile emulators. I just wanted to know how should we do the same in browserstack.

Similar to local chrome execution, just have to open a chrome browser with the given chrome options(android,ipad,iphone) in browserstack.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation

Local chrome Execution code snippet:

```
`"chromeAndroid": {
"deviceName": "Nexus 5"
},
"chromeiPhone": {
"deviceName": "iPhone 5"
},
"chromeiPad": {
"deviceName": "iPad"
},
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);`
```

We are parsing the data from above json file and pass it onto the chrome options.

Local chrome execution Screenshot:
[image]
Please suggest me by providing some details or code snippet for remoteWebdriver as we are running the browser stack tests from Jenkins and browserstack local.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the "mobile emulation in chrome browser" in browserstack? If it's a desktop Chrome with the mobile emulation enabled (according to your code) then everything should work the same as locally.

If you are testing Chrome in a physical device in browserstack then you need to pass a few more capabilities like

- *realMobile* - should be set to **true**
- *device* - specify a device
- *os_version* - OS version of a device you want to test
- *browserstack.appium_version* - Appium version

You can find more by the [link](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/physical-mobile-devices)

Also, [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver) is a guide on Selenium tests with Chrome

Comment: I don't need to test in physical device for now. In browserstack, trying to automate the mobile emulation in chrome browser & its not working with local code.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation

Please suggest me with piece of code to run in mobile emulation, not in real device.Thanks